# Pass -e command to the Ansible make module

Tags: makefile, ansible, parameter-passing

I want to execute Makefile on one of my Ansible provisioned servers with flag -e but Ansible make module does not seem to support this (just key-values)

Is there any other way of doing that, other than: "command: make -e my_target"?

[Ansible make module docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/make_module.html#options)

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be any code in the module to support what you are looking for. If you want the module to be extended, I'd suggest raising an issue against it at [github.com/ansible](http://github.com/ansible).